# Do I need to Reload the Site in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have this Template:

```
<template name="body">
  {{#if key}}
    {{> mite}}
  {{else}}
    {{> settings}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

and

```
<template name="settings">
  <h1>The settings</h1>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input id='apiKey' type='text' name='apiKey' placeholder='your API-Key'>
    <button id='saveSettings' type='submit' class='btn'>save</button>
  </form>
</template>

<template name="mite">
  <div>
    <h3>...here with key</h3>
    <p>
      <a id="optout" href="#">not your key?</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I show the settings-form where the user can set the key needed to show the 'mite' template. Now when i 'submit' the form the page get reloaded and the 'mite' template is shown.

On the mite template I'd like to have that link 'not your key?' or something that deletes the key and then shows the settings-form again. It works with a reload... but can't I do this without all the reloading in Meteor? How can i 'call' the template part with the #if in the body template?

-- Renato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind an event handler to your form and use `preventDefault()` to stop it submitting. e.g

**client side js**

```
Template.settings.events({
    'submit':function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var apiKey = template.find('input[name=apiKey]').value;

        //..rest of logic to handle submit event
        Session.set("key",true);
    }
});
```

You can then use a template helper with `Session.get("showthistemplate")` to decide whether to show another template or not: (this is a universal helper since you're putting it in  and not a template:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('key',function() {
    return Session.set("key",true);
});
```

Comment: but the site still needs a reload, right? what I'm trying to do is that template 'mite' is rendered as soon as the key is set...

Comment: Nooo, the template system is 'reactive' with meteor. So as soon as `Session.set('key',true)` is set or changed Meteor will automatically patch the DOM with the update without the need for a reload. Its really quite cool!

Comment: Ah! Session... that was it. 
`Template.body.key = -> Session.get 'key'` works but `Template.body.key = -> localStorage['key']` didn't. Thank you!